# R unused argument error in homemade function using stats package

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Edited to clarify dataset:

I am trying to write a function so I can calculate a weighted mean and median for multiple numeric variables, and show them together.

I have two versions of the dataset that I want to be able to run the function on for comparison.

`Ind1` is a series of monetary values, ranging from 0 to 2000.
The weights are decimal values between 0 and 4, and this needs specifying as different variables use different weights.

The vectors `Ind1` and `firstwt` below are part of the larger data frame `dataset_a` -  I have shown them to give an example of the actual data. Each run of the function will use a different indicator variable, and the relevant weight for the variable.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(spatstat)

#Sample data
Ind1 = (0, 0, 290.50, 100, 0, 150.00, 2000.00, 1350.50, 320.00, 30.00)
firstwt = (0.974, 2.11, 1.81, 0.817, 3.85, 2.33, 1.41, 1.37, 1.83, 1.57)

summary_stats <- function(indicator, weight){
  summarise(mean = stats::weighted.mean(indicator, weight, na.rm = TRUE),
           median = weighted.median(indicator, weight, na.rm = TRUE))
}
dataset_a %>%
summary_stats(Ind1, weight = firstwt)

Error in summary_stats(., Ind1, weight = firstwt) : unused argument (Ind1)
```

I have also tried specifying the dataset as the first item in the function, then piping it to the summarise, so
`summary_stats <- function(data, indicator, weight){ data %>% summarise...` but I get an unused argument error for the dataset if I do that.

Comment: Your `summary_stats()` takes two arguments. When you pipe the first input from `dataset_a` it gets consumed as the first argument, i.e. `indicator`. Then the value for the `weight` argument is matched by name. Then R tries to pass `Ind1` to whatever is left, but there is no argument left to be assigned to. Official explanation: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching.

Comment: @rmagn0, If I specify the different parts, and put the data source in the function, I still get: `Error in summary_stats(., data = dataset_a, indicator = Ind1, weight = firstwt) : 
  unused arguments (., data = dataset_a)`. How do I actually get it to process the arguments correctly and make the function work?

Comment: To help you further I think it might be useful for you to try to run your code without the pipe. Then improve your post by making a reproducible example, in your case you need to provide an example of what `dataset_a` might have looked like, so that your code runs fully.

Comment: The `%>%` pipe puts whatever comes before the pipe as the first argument of what comes after the pipe. That is the sole purpose of the pipe. `a %>% mean()` is the same as `mean(a)`. In your code, `dataset_a %>%
summary_stats(Ind1, weight = firstwt)` is the same as `summary_stats(dataset_a, Ind1, weight = firstwt)`. But your `summary_stats` function takes 2 arguments and you are giving it 3. If you want to use the function this way, I would suggest rewriting it so that the first argument is a data frame in which to look for the columns. Perhaps  using `dplyr::mutate` internally.

Comment: The [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) vignette is a great place to start for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to summarize is the data frame and that is missing.  If we add that then it works.  Using the same setup as in the question this creates a data frame for use in the first argument of summarize. It  pipes that data frame to summarize which has the effect of inserting it in the first argument of summarize.

```
summary_stats2 <- function(indicator, weight) {
  data.frame(indicator, weight) %>%
    summarise(mean = stats::weighted.mean(indicator, weight, na.rm = TRUE),
              median = weighted.median(indicator, weight, na.rm = TRUE))
}

summary_stats2(Ind1, weight = firstwt)
##       mean median
## 1 346.4053     65
```

Even easier is this solution which does not use dplyr:

```
summary_stats3 <- function(indicator, weight) {
    data.frame(mean = stats::weighted.mean(indicator, weight, na.rm = TRUE),
               median = weighted.median(indicator, weight, na.rm = TRUE))
}

summary_stats3(Ind1, weight = firstwt)
##       mean median
## 1 346.4053     65
```

### Update

In the comments the poster stated that the setup actually wanted is one where the variables are in a data frame so let change the problem and answer to this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(spatstat)

DF <- data.frame(Ind1 = c(0, 0, 290.50, 100, 0, 150.00, 2000.00, 
                        1350.50, 320.00, 30.00),
                 firstwt = c(0.974, 2.11, 1.81, 0.817, 3.85, 2.33, 
                           1.41, 1.37, 1.83, 1.57))

summary_stats4 <- function(data, indicator, weight){
  data %>% summarise(
    mean = stats::weighted.mean({{indicator}}, {{weight}}, na.rm = TRUE),
    median = weighted.median({{indicator}}, {{weight}}, na.rm = TRUE))
}

DF %>% summary_stats4(Ind1, firstwt)
```

Comment: @G-Grothendieck How do I specify the dataset I'm using then? I need to be able to compare a couple of versions of the data.

Comment: The question does not use a data frame. It passes two plain vectors so we must construct the data frame if we want to use summarize.

Comment: Ind1 and firstwt are both columns in the larger dataset I am wrangling. I was just trying to show what they look like with the vectors, but I said in the original question I have different versions of the data, and multiple similar looking variables.

Comment: I have added what I think may be your question and the answer to it.

Comment: I think we were both rewriting the question at the same time, Thanks, that now works - I have been tearing my hair out over this for several days!